# Get a list of items (like a SQL IN clause)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table of items where each item belongs to an organization.  Each item has a name and an auto-generated UUID. The name of the item is meant to be unique within an organization.  Thus, I have defined my table as such:

```
{
  "AttributeDefinitions": [
    { "AttributeName": "orgId",            "AttributeType": "S" },
    { "AttributeName": "name",             "AttributeType": "S" },
    { "AttributeName": "id",               "AttributeType": "S" }
  ],
  "TableName": "symbols",
  "KeySchema": [
    { "AttributeName": "orgId", "KeyType": "HASH" },
    { "AttributeName": "name",  "KeyType": "RANGE" }
  ],
  "LocalSecondaryIndexes": [
    {
      "IndexName": "IdIndex",
      "KeySchema": [
        { "AttributeName": "orgId", "KeyType": "HASH" },
        { "AttributeName": "id",    "KeyType": "RANGE" }
      ],
      "Projection": {
        "ProjectionType": "KEYS_ONLY"
      }
    }
  ],
  "ProvisionedThroughput": {
    "ReadCapacityUnits": 10,
    "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
  },
  "SSESpecification": {
    "Enabled": true
  }
}
```

I am trying to retrieve the set of items that match a specified list of ids.  My java code looks like this:

```
List<AttributeValue> attributeValueList = new ArrayList<>();
String[] idList = {"d329e1f8-9705-4ec2-95a9-135379e32090", "ddcc98e9-9a55-4c2c-b329-ed696b1bcc5c"};
for (String id : idList) {
    attributeValueList.add(new AttributeValue().withS(id));
}

HashMap<String, Condition> keyConditions = new HashMap<>();

keyConditions.put("orgId", new Condition()
        .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
        .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue("111")));

keyConditions.put("id", new Condition()
        .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.IN)
        .withAttributeValueList(attributeValueList));

QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest()
        .withTableName(Symbol.TABLE_SYMBOL)
        .withKeyConditions(keyConditions)
        .withIndexName("IdIndex")
        .withSelect("ALL_ATTRIBUTES");

QueryResult queryResult = dynamoDB.query(queryRequest);
```

When I run the query, it gives me the exception:

> **Attempted conditional constraint is not an indexable operation**

Any ideas on why this doesn't work?  Do I need to use a scan instead?  I would like to stick to a query if possible.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to do something similar, here's what worked.

```
    List<AttributeValue> attributeValueList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String id : objectIds) {
        attributeValueList.add(new AttributeValue().withS(id));
    }

    TextFragment partitionKey = new TextFragment();
    partitionKey.setOrgId(user.getOrgId());

    Condition rangeKeyCondition = new Condition();
    rangeKeyCondition.withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.IN)
            .withAttributeValueList(attributeValueList);

    DynamoDBQueryExpression<TextFragment> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<TextFragment>()
            .withHashKeyValues(partitionKey)
            .withQueryFilterEntry("id", rangeKeyCondition);

    List<TextFragment> itemList = mapper.query(TextFragment.class, queryExpression);
```